# I need to know how to keep exiting navigation tab content when I refresh the browser,When there is a default tab in HTML,CSS,JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have Created a HTML page with four tabs including one default tab with details in that default tab. But when I was in another tab I have refreshed the page and it was returned the default tab content.
But I need to create my page, when I refresh the page on non-default tab, I need to stay the same tab.
This is the html code.

```
<nav id="navBar">
        <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Home',this);" style="margin-left: 100px">Home</button>
        <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Map',this);">Map</button>
        <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('About',this);">About Us</button>
        <button class="tablink" onclick="openPage('Contact',this);">Contact Us</button>
    </nav>

    <div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>This is home</h3>
        <p>welcome to the home</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Map" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>This is Map</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="About" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>This is About</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="Contact" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>This is contact</h3>
    </div>
<script>
function openPage(pageName,elmnt) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  elmnt.style.backgroundColor = '#2f3542';
}
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

Here is my style sheet

```
#navBar{
    background-color: #555;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.tablink{
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:14px 16px;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.tablink:hover{
    background-color: #777;
}
.tabcontent{
    color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I have learned this code in www.w3schools.com site. Please help me to solve this problem...

Comment: You would need a way for the page to "remember" what tab you're looking at when refreshing, since the default is what the page renders by default. There are quite a few ways to approach this, especially if you're using a server side language like php. Since all I see is javascript in your code, you could try taking a look at localstorage or sessionstorage to see which one would make more sense for what you're trying to do.